# Qt Program runs slow if object parent is the window

Tags: c++, performance, qt, parent

I got a strange behaviour in Qt and I would like to know why thing are happening this way, if someone can clarify this to me it will be most welcome.

I have a object that belongs to the mainWindow, when I construct this object in the mainWindow's initialization list, I send 0 as the parent and the program runs fast, as it should.

BUT if I pass `this` in the constructor, making the main window the parent of the object, the program runs incredibly slow!

I mean, the GUI runs slow, the buttons take time to respond. There is NOTHING being processed or executed, since processing just start when I click something, and still the buttons take time to become pressed or highlighted.

One thing to add, in the mainWindow's constructor the object is moved to another thread. When I trigger the object processing routine, the GUI comes back to life...not as fast as it was when `parent` was 0, but a lot faster.

Does anyone know why's this is happening? I am not using the parent to do anything, so this must be Qt's inner workings.

I would post my code in here, but it's huge and I have no idea which part is related to this.

Comment: You shouldn't be able to move an object to a thread if it has a parent. The docs: [*The object cannot be moved if it has a parent*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#moveToThread).

Comment: This makes lots of sense...mind posting it as the answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You shouldn't be able to move objects to a thread if they have a parent. The docs: [*The object cannot be moved if it has a parent*](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtcore/qobject.html#moveToThread).

You should also get a warning message if you try to do so. If you look at the [source code](https://qt.gitorious.org/qt/qt/source/fd529383c4491580db344fb3d8035bd0ad3cb5e0%3asrc/corelib/kernel/qobject.cpp#L1455) of `QObject::moveToThread` you will find the following lines:

```
if (d->parent != 0) {
        qWarning("QObject::moveToThread: Cannot move objects with a parent");
        return;
    }
```

Comment: Never saw this warning, probably because I am in VS2010?

Comment: @mFeinstein Nothing to do with VS2010, everything to do with you either ignoring the debug console output, or not running debug builds in the first place. Please make sure that you can see the debug output of your application - add a `qDebug() << "Hello World!"` into the body of `main()` before the call to `app.exec()`.

Comment: Yes, I can see it in the `output` window, but I was expecting to see it in the `warnings` window many thanks!